# Executing two functions in exactly the same time

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

im pretty new in Obj-C, and im wondering how to execute two functions in exactly the same time(with an accuracy to 1ms) without waiting for return, on different theards.

Currently i tried with

```
#define kBgQueue1 dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)  
dispatch_sync(kBgQueue1, ^{
    [self function1];
    });
    dispatch_sync(kBgQueue1, ^{
    [self function2];
    });
```

Comment: Don't make macro names starting with `k` that are actually function calls. `k` is for "constant".

Comment: while this might work in theory, OS X is not a realtime system. Thus exact timing doesn't need to work with high granularity. What is the actual goal you want to achieve?

Comment: I need to execute two NSURL calls in exactly the same time, it's possible?

Comment: @user3370412: Can you explain *why* that is necessary? Perhaps there is a better solution.

Comment: Even if you execute the two NSURLs at the same time, there is no guarantee that the queries reach the NSURL target at the same time. Routing to the destination is dynamic and the server doesn't need to receive or work on the requests at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

`dispatch_get_global_queue()` gives you a *concurrent* queue, which can execute
tasks in parallel. But you have to use
`dispatch_async()` to execute the blocks without waiting for them to complete.

Note however that Grand Central Dispatch makes no guarantee about the timing.
Also GCD uses a limited thread pool, so there is also no guarantee that
the blocks are executed "simultaneously".

If you need more control about the thread creation then you would have to use lower-level classes/functions
such as `NSThread` or `pthread_create()`.

As @Volker already said in a comment, you don't have 100% control over the 
*timing* on OS X or iOS.

For more information, see the ["Concurrency Programming Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: @user3370412: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html has sample code. - But NSURLConnection (and network connections in general) is an asynchronous process, so even if you manage to *initiate* them in the same millisecond, there is no guarantee that they reach the server at the same time.

Comment: @user3370412: Your code (with `dispatch_async()`) *should* start both blocks almost simultaneously. You can add `NSLog(@"start: %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]);` as the first line of each block to verify that. - I assume that your problem is the timing of network connections (over which you have almost control).

Comment: there is any simplest example? i found performSelectorInBackground but i don't think that this could work better than dispatch_async.
You have right, but i noticed that program is waiting till first function is done, becouse sometimes interval between each call is around 50ms and sometimes it's 5s...

Comment: @user3370412: Are you sure that you have replaced `dispatch_sync()` by `dispatch_async()`? `dispatch_async()` is already the simplest example, and it does *not* wait for the first function to return.

Comment: so why intervals are diferrent?

Comment: @user3370412: What values do you get for the timestamps?

Comment: 2014-03-02 10:54:18.303 nslog from function1
2014-03-02 10:54:19.901 f2  with using async

Comment: @user3370412: Have you added the NSLogs to the block, *before* calling function1 or function2?

Comment: Finally is used [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(method) toTarget:self withObject:nil];  and it's starts functions at the same time.  Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: @user3370412: I am glad that you solved your problem, and using `NSThread` was one suggestion in my answer. - Note that you can "accept" an answer if it helped by clicking on the check mark. That marks the problem as solved, and gives some reputation points to you and to the author of the answer.